# Can't run a python file - perhaps because it doesn't have the extension?

Tags: python, github

I have installed a programme called ReconDog.

I have Python installed and all I am trying to do is run the file called "dog" which you can see in the image below.

[image]

I have changed the file permissions by running

```
chmod +x dog
```

as well as

```
chmod +x dog.py
```

Then when I try to run the file through

```
python dog
```

or

```
python dog.py
```

I get this error:

[image]

Any idea how to make this work?

Here's the Github URL: 
https://github.com/s0md3v/ReconDog

Thanks

Comment: Why, you _can_ indeed run the file. The problem is that an error occurs while running it.

Comment: The error is telling you that you're missing a dependency

Comment: did you install the `requirements`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you don't install requirements.

```
pip install tld
```

and after get tld should it work.

Answer (score 1):

The top line of the `dog` file is this:
`#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Maybe your Python interpreter is located somewhere else? Try looking for it with `which python3` and update the file with the correct location. After you do this, you should be able to run the file simply by typing dog, like you see in the project's demo video.

Or, just run the file by typing `python3 dog`. It doesn't look as cool, but it saves you from editing the files.

Also, of course, create a virtualenv for your project and install everything from the requirements.txt file. That will handle the dependency issue you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a program in bash, you need to specify the path to the program or the program itself if it is in one of the system's known `PATH`, so in your case you need to use `python3 ./dog`, (`./` meaning in the current directory) (the file extension has no effect on the file)

Answer (score -1):

looks like you're missing a requirement "tld":

try downloading it. steps can be found here:

https://pypi.org/project/tld/

hope this helps